# w3 Validate html error

Tags: html, xhtml

I am still a newbie, I am a little confuse with what this errors mean.

```
 Line 30, Column 5: document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol" start-tag
```

i got this error all the way till line 44

and what this omitted mean?

```
 Line 54, Column 7: end tag for "div" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified
```

below is my code: (thanks if anyone could guide me

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content= "about" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="about" />
<title>About</title>
</head>  
    <body>
        <div id="container">
        <div id="inside">
        <div id="inside2">
        <h1>About</h1>
        <ul>
        <li>The Php version installed in mercury is <?php echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion(); ?>.
        </li>
        <br />
        <li>The task I am not attempted is Task 5.
        </li>
        <br />
        <li>I am not exploring and implementing any special feature.</li>
        <br />
        <li>I have trouble mainly on Task 3 with validation.</li>
        <br />
        <li>Regarding with php, I want to gain more knowledge, I need to grasp deeper understanding on how everything works
        as there are a lot of things to remember and how things are working. The other part is I need to dramatically improve
        my time managment, although I start a week and half early, but I had trouble understanding the codes, and with other
        assignments I need to finish.</li>
        <br />
        <li>Youtube channel by the name phpacademy and thenewboston help me out to get clearer understanding about certain stuff
        in php, as well stackoverflow.com</li>
        <li>I have learn more and new codes, better understanding on how overall the code works in PHP, but still a lot to learn.</li>
        <br />
        <img src="thread.jpg" width="450" height="350" alt="Discussion Thread" />
        <br />
        <a href="index.php">Return to Homepage</a> 


        <ul>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first message, any `<li>`s must be children of a `<ul>`.  For the second message, you open three `<div>`s but never close them.  The `<br />`s are also invalid and redundant; the `<li>`s will break lines automatically.  Your HTML can be fixed as shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content= "about" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="about" />
<title>About</title>
</head>  
<body>
    <div id="container">
    <div id="inside">
    <div id="inside2">
    <h1>About</h1>
    <ul>
    <li>The Php version installed in mercury is <?php echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion(); ?>.
    </li>
    <li>The task I am not attempted is Task 5.</li>
    <li>I am not exploring and implementing any special feature.</li>
    <li>I have trouble mainly on Task 3 with validation.</li>
    <li>Regarding with php, I want to gain more knowledge, I need to grasp deeper understanding on how everything works
    as there are a lot of things to remember and how things are working. The other part is I need to dramatically improve
    my time managment, although I start a week and half early, but I had trouble understanding the codes, and with other
    assignments I need to finish.</li>
    <li>Youtube channel by the name phpacademy and thenewboston help me out to get clearer understanding about certain stuff
    in php, as well stackoverflow.com</li>
    <li>I have learn more and new codes, better understanding on how overall the code works in PHP, but still a lot to learn.</li>
    <li>
        <img src="thread.jpg" width="450" height="350" alt="Discussion Thread" />
        <a href="index.php">Return to Homepage</a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ahhh ok ok, but I tried closing div after each of those divs, <div></div> and suddenly i got another 3 error for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Your `<br/>` tags are throwing off the validation.  Remove them, or at least put them within a proper element.  For the other errors, close your tags properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing a `</ul>` before after your last `</li>`. Then close your last `<div>` with `</div>`...I'm pretty sure that should do the trick.  Also all the breaks are bad formatting you can change those styles using CSS, and it would be more browser compatible.

Answer (score 0):

check your closing ul tag at the bottom. 
It seems to be `<ul>` and should be `</ul>` (you have an opening tag instead of a closing tag).

Keep in mind XHTML 1.0 Strict means just that...strict.

Answer (score 0):

This should validate better.

There was two open `<ul>` tags and no one closing tags, 3 `</div>`'s were missing and lot of `<br>`'s b/w `<li>`'s.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en" >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta name="description" content= "about" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="about" />
<title>About</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
          <div id="inside">
            <div id="inside2">
            <h1>About</h1>
            <ul>
              <li>The Php version installed in mercury is <?php echo 'Current PHP version: ' . phpversion(); ?>.</li>
              <li>The task I am not attempted is Task 5.</li>
              <li>I am not exploring and implementing any special feature.</li>
              <li>I have trouble mainly on Task 3 with validation.</li>
              <li>Regarding with php, I want to gain more knowledge, I need to grasp deeper understanding on how everything works
              as there are a lot of things to remember and how things are working. The other part is I need to dramatically improve
              my time managment, although I start a week and half early, but I had trouble understanding the codes, and with other
              assignments I need to finish.</li>
              <li>Youtube channel by the name phpacademy and thenewboston help me out to get clearer understanding about certain stuff
              in php, as well stackoverflow.com</li>
              <li>I have learn more and new codes, better understanding on how overall the code works in PHP, but still a lot to learn.</li>
            </ul>
            <img src="thread.jpg" width="450" height="350" alt="Discussion Thread" />
            <br>
            <a href="index.php">Return to Homepage</a>    
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```